# Finding the parameter regime for prevalence of Chimera states in case of diffusively coupled Rossler system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

I think there exists a parameter regime in which Chimera states exist in case of diffusively coupled Rossler systems (100 in numbers) in any simple topology.

Is there some method we can find those parameters or estimate them?.

Like it seems after going through some of the research papers that it requires a parameter search computationally and I think it may take more computational load and finding I.C for the prevalence of Chimera states is still ongoing research.

Comment: Just a few words of concern about network topology. Take them with caution, I'm not an expert in chimera states. To my understanding chimera states were really surprising and unexpected in case of networks of identical elements with non-local coupling but still with a non-trivial set of system and network symmetries. For example, many papers consider a ring topology of a network; it also can be a homogeneous medium like in [Kuramoto-Battogtokh model](http://www.j-npcs.org/online/vol2002/v5no4/v5no4p380.pdf). But in case of general network chimera-state behaviour is much less surprising ...

Comment: ... — it's a kind of maxima (maybe a false one), but in general system you can in principle get any kind of behaviour (some complications and assumptions are quietly swept under the rug here). Again, this is sort of a personal opinion, so take it with caution, I can be mistaken. I'll be gladly corrected if someone else here "digs" chimera states.